How to calculate the w and b of linear regression with python using the loss function?
My goal is to create a ipynb file to learn about how to create a Linear Regression Model.
The problem:

How to set the initial w and b, should I set it randomly?
When to change the w or b on each iteration.
By how many should I update the w or b on each iteration.

Expected result:

There is a Model class with a __init__ and fit function.
The fit function will increment or decrement the w or b on each iteration.

What I've tried:

Creating the graph

plt.xlim(-2, 11)
plt.ylim(-2, 11)

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = [-1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 10, 9]
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')

# y = x
x = [0,10]
y = [0,10]
plt.plot(x, y)

# fill_between
x = [0, 10]
y1 = [-1, 9]
y2 = [1, 11]
plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2, alpha=0.2)

del x, y


Creating a loss function.

# Dots
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = [-1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 10, 9]

# calculated from y = 1x + 0
ŷ = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

# The loss function of linear regression is (ŷ - y)²
# Other name is: the residual
def calculate_linear_regression_loss_function(ŷ: list[int], y: list[int]) -> list[int]:
  # Map to numpy array (for syntatic sugar)
  np_ŷ = np.array(ŷ)
  np_y = np.array(y)
  # Measure distance between ŷ and y
  distances = np_ŷ - np_y
  # Square each distance
  squares = distances ** 2
  # sum the squares
  return squares.sum()

print(calculate_linear_regression_loss_function(ŷ, y))

del x, ŷ, y


Create the generate training data function

def generate_training_data(n: int) -> list[list[int]]:
    training_data: list[list[int]] = []

    for _ in range(n):
        x = randrange(0, 1000) / 100
        y = randrange(0, 1000) / 100
        training_data.append([x, y])

    return training_data

generate_training_data(n=10)

def separate_training_data_into_x_y(training_data: list[list[int]]) -> tuple[list[int], list[int]]:
    array = np.array(training_data)
    return array[:,0], array[:, 1]

training_data = generate_training_data(n=10)
print("training_data", training_data)

x_training, y_training = separate_training_data_into_x_y(training_data=training_data)
print("x_training", x_training)

training_data = generate_training_data(10)
x_training, y_training = separate_training_data_into_x_y(training_data=training_data)

plt.plot(x_training, y_training, 'ro')

For example, how to estimate the initial w and b of

TLDR, unfinished line of code
The Model class. I was going to do this after I understand how Linear Regression works.
# Reference:
# 1. https://medium.com/deep-learning-construction/neural-network-build-from-scratch-without-frameworks-1-302dcfb46127

# What is the learning objectives of deep learning?
# To minimize the value of the loss function
# For example, a linear regression y = w*x + b
# the weights (w), and bias (b) are adjusted during the training process
# the loss function is (ŷ - y)² where ŷ is the prediction and y is the actual value.

from typing import Callable

class Model:
    x_train: list[list[int]]
    loss_function: Callable[[int, int], int]

    def __init__(self,
                 loss_function: Callable[[int, int], int]):
        self.loss_function = loss_function
        
    def fit(self, x_training: list[list[int]], y_training: list[int]):
        self.x_training = x_training
        self.y_training = y_training
        print(self.loss_function(3,1))

loss_function: Callable[[int, int], int] = lambda ŷ, y: (ŷ - y)**2
model = Model(loss_function)
model.fit([[1], [1]], [1])


can you post your code for the Model class please?

@James Hi, I added the Model class. However, it's unfinished.

"How to set the initial w and b, should I set it randomly?" Typically you wouldn't initialize this randomly. This can be necessary for initializing multi-layer neural networks, but since you only have one layer in a linear regression, this isn't required. Usually you'd initialize both to zero.
